# Skype Bot unable to join group chats (was able to before)

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

I have a skype bot which was working fine and was able to join and interact in Group Calls
Now (July 27th) it seems to have stopped working

If I try to add the bot to a Group Call I get the initial callback. But my Answer Action does not seem to get the subsequent callback from the Skype Channel.
Note: The call is successfully joined if it's only 1:1, not a Group Call.

I have Group Messaging "on". (Since it was working earlier)
I have tried this on our Production Bot, QA Bot, and even a bot for my local development. All Group Calls have ceased on all (different) bots.
I have tried calling the Bot 1:1, successfully, and then adding somebody to the conversation. This also does not work as the third person is unable to join the call (no reason specified).

Has this functionality been removed entirely?

Comment: Report this issue on GitHub here: [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder). Thanks

Comment: Will, thanks. Although I am using the REST API. Not C#, or node.js

Comment: For those interested, I posted this bug https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3216